# Why is there no warning about a possible mistaken empty statement in an empty "while" loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings

There are *tons* of posts about [compiler warning CS0642: "Possible mistaken empty statement"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0642), and I understand what it's all about.  For example, the `FileStream` instance `f` isn't used, so that's probably a mistake:

```
using (var f = File.OpenRead("f.txt")) ; // Possible mistaken empty statement
```

However, this `while` statement *does not* produce the warning, even though there's no opportunity for `x` to ever become equal to or greater than `3`.  Why?

```
int x = 1;
while (x < 3) ; // why no warning?
```

Here's an example where the warning is present but the `Timer` instance `t` actually *can* do something, i.e. fire the call-back:

```
using (var t = new Timer((x) => Debug.Print("This"), null, 500, 500)) ; // warning
```

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: About the while, you can also do: while (true)

Comment: About the timer, I think the Warning is about 'x'

Comment: @PoulBak -- Yes I know you can do `while (true)` but mine demonstrates that it happens when dealing with a variable that otherwise could be modified in the while statement/block in order to achieve the exit condition.  And no the warning is definitely not about `x`.  There's not even an `x` in the first statement with the `FileStream`.

Comment: I suppose it's just a matter of what the the compiler team thought was helpful. Historically in other languages, empty while statements have had a lot of use; empty `using` which is new in C#, not so much.

Comment: Calling this an "inconsistency" seems disingenuous. Would you expect the compiler to have domain knowledge of `Timer`? The whole reason it's a warning, and not an error, is because the compiler isn't sure. "Why doesn't the compiler warn on a `while` condition that's always true" (i.e. the "x" example) is a valid but separate question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert -- No I wouldn't expect the compiler to have knowledge of Timer.  I'd expect a warning in every case, including the `while`, which is what I'm thinking is inconsistent.

Comment: CS0642 is actually pretty clever, as it seems designed to catch obvious *typographical* mistakes more than *semantic* mistakes: `while (x < 3) ;` does not trigger the warning, but `while (x < 3); { ... }` *does*. I'd guess that `while (always-true-condition) ;` occurs commonly enough in valid code that it was excluded (and in any case, it would take a different kind of check).

Comment: Note also that `using (...) {}` does not trigger the warning either -- empty *blocks* are fine in any case, as you obviously didn't typo those. An empty block might still be a mistake, but not one CS0642 cares about. (This also explains why I can't recall having seen it in recent memory -- I never use a solitary `;` in places where a block would be expected.)

Comment: Compiler writers are never that keen on having to solve the Halting problem or producing a false diagnostic when a variable *might* be accessed by another thread.  It is quite common to write a while loop that relies only on the side-effects of the expression.  Bad idea, but not illegal.  Analyzing the possible side-effects of an expression is quite hard to do, parsing them is a convoluted affair in all of the curly-brace languages.  Humans are much better at it then programs, equipped with excellent pattern recognition hardware between their ears :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. CS0642 is not about validating that your code is meaningful, or ever executed, it's only intended to catch some syntactical patterns that might represent a mistake. Compare:

```
int x = 1;
while (x < 3) {}   // no warning
while (x < 3); {}  // CS0642
if (x < 3) ;       // CS0642
using (new object() as IDisposable) ;  // CS0642
using (new object() as IDisposable) {} // no warning
for (; x < 3 ;) ;  // empty statement *and* condition is always true, still no warning
```

Writing empty loops with a single `;` instead of `{ }` is a common C idiom that programmers brought with them (for better or worse); having these always trigger CS0642 likely produced too many false positives. `using`, however, was never a C idiom, so enforcing that empty blocks always be written as `{ }` seems reasonable. It certainly catches some cases where you could get it wrong:

```
TextWriter x = null;
using (x) ;  // CS0642
    x.WriteLine();  // whoops, use of disposed object
```

Admittedly, this is not a likely pattern, and wrapping even single statements in blocks is always good practice -- even in C.

Incidentally, if it had been up to Eric Lippert, there'd have been no `;` at all, and it would be `{ }` everywhere:

> The empty statement feature is redundant, rarely needed, and
>   error-prone, and it creates work for the compiler team to implement a
>   warning telling you not to use it. The feature could simply have been
>   cut from C# 1.0.
>   [(Source.)](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867)

A follow-up question would be why the C# compiler makes no apparent effort to warn about any non-trivial conditions that are always `true` or `false`, which is a fairly common feature of C compilers. The compiler has *some* warnings for expressions that are always `true` or `false` (like CS0464, "Comparing with null of type 'type' always produces 'false'") but not general ones. There's likely a design decision behind this, and I may even have seen Eric Lippert blog about it once -- or maybe I just imagined that one. In any case, getting no warnings there has nothing to do with CS0642.

Comment: There's no principled general reason I'm aware of justifying why the C# compiler does not detect as many "always true / always false" conditions as it could. It has simply not been a high priority of the compiler team compared to feature work, and so it doesn't get done. If you think it should be a priority, you might mention it on the Roslyn github forum.

Comment: I'd also love it if the compiler were smarter about the more general issue of "expression always has the same value but involves variables", and "conversion is too late".  These are common sources of questions on SO; I see all the time "percent = (double)(x / 100);" where x is an integer from 0 to 100, and of course percent is always zero or one.